# Docker compose, webpack permission denied

Tags: docker, webpack, docker-compose

I am trying to run webpack inside a docker container for a node app.  I get the following error.

```
sh: 1: webpack: Permission denied
```

The Dockerfile works fine on a normal build.

```
FROM node

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/

RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 3001

#This launches webpack which fails.
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Comment: Please post your `Dockerfile` and what is the difference between your build and a normal build?

Comment: this is my Dockerfile thats failing
FROM node

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 3001
CMD [ "npm", "start" ] #This launches webpack which fails.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, as I was migrating an existing project to docker. I resolved it by not copying the entire project contents (`COPY . /usr/src/app` in your docker file) and instead only copying the files and directories actually required.

In my case, the unnecessary directories added when copying the whole project were, among other things, `node_modules`, the build directory and the entire `.git` repo directory.

I still don't know why copying the entire directory doesn't work (something conflicts with something? something has incorrect permissions?), but copying only what you need is better for image size anyway.